# Reprojecting DWG file using AutoCAD?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, autocad, dwg

I can't remember if AutoCAD supports reprojecting layers from a projection/datum to an other projection/datum.

My first question is : **could it be done on AutoCAD?**

Second question, which matters more to me -since I'm a GIS person - is : **could it be done by ArcGIS or QGIS or any of the other GIS softwares ?**

I've done some research on the internet, it turns out that a georeferencing of a CAD file is possible in ArcGIS, but what's a georeferencing operation worth if the spatial reference of the file is wrong in the first place ?

***Note*** : of course one can think of using the interoperability tool in ArcGIS, convert a DWG to a SHP, reproject the SHP then finally re-convert to DWG. I'm looking for a simplier solution.

***Detailed description*** : we have a DWG file in the "Lambert Conical Conformal Zone 1 / Clark 1880" for Morocco, and we want to know if it can be possible to reproject it into "UTM Zone 30N" (WGS84). This question would've not had posed any problem if it was a Shapefile, as you would imagine. Thus, the question is in short : what are known ways to reproject DWG files from their spatial reference to a target spatial reference.

Comment: This is far too broad, please try to break it in several smaller and more objective questions.

Comment: Hi, I don't think the question can be divided into any more questions, the thing is that we have a DWG file in the "Lambert Conical Conformal Zone 1 / Clark 1880" for Morocco, and we want to know if it can be possible to reproject it into "UTM Zone 30N" (WGS84). This question would've not had posed any  problem if it was a Shapefile, as you would imagine. Thus, the question is in short : what are known ways to reproject DWG files from their spatial reference to a target spatial reference. I hope it clear now, thanks !

Comment: That detail needs to be in the question (not lost in a comment). Please click edit below the question to update it with this important information.

Comment: Ok, let me do that @BradHards !

Comment: @gloserio: In which software you want to use the DGW after the DWG is converted? If you want to use it in ArcGIS you do not need to reproject it to a new DWG. ArcGIS is can reproject a DWG on-the-fly.

Comment: I prefer ArcGIS. So if I open a project in the target spatial reference the DWG will be reprojected in it ?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AutoCAD Map 3D to reproject DWGs. The transformation of the datum is supported in this process too.

The steps are well documented in [AutoCAD Map 3D help](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAP/2013/ENU/index.html):
Use AutoCAD Map 3D > Task Workflows > Work with Coordinate Systems > Transform a DWG File to a Different Coordinate System

Here's a summary:

- Create a new DWG
- Assigning the target coordinate system to the new DWG
- *Attach* original drawing
- *Query* all objects from attached DWG
- *Detach* DWG
- Save new DWG.

Comment: Oh, many thanks ! I looked it up, seems like it's not the standard autocad, is it an extension ?

Comment: [AutoCAD Map 3D](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autodesk-autocad-map-3d/overview) is a desktop GIS while AutoCAD is a CAD. AutoCAD Map 3D is bases on AutoCAD but it is a seperate product/license.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this in ArcGIS for Desktop when I:

1. Defined the spatial reference of the DWG in ArcCatalog.
2. Exported the DWG to a GDB (in ArcCatalog).
3. Opened the annotation in the DWG in ArcMap, and converted to Geodatabase Annotation in the GDB, and deleted the point annotation (created from insertion points) already there. (used 1:1000 scale reference. Not sure how much effect different scales would have)
4. Made sure data was in the correct projection, then projected it into target projection in a GDB.
5. Opened all files in blank ArcMap file, and exported to CAD.

The results were great. The annotation had moved by about 1/10th of a character width, which was completely acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FME](http://www.safe.com/) it will interpret the current projection and transpose to the format and projection you specify too easy quick savable workflow and not set to the one output thus able to be shared with others with differing software.

The real question is what happens when the `dwg` comes in no format and no location information. You will need the location in geographical/projected format for the survey points for the drawing so as to relocate the whole data to the origin of the drawing.